# Read .nc files from Azure Datalake Gen2 in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, netcdf, netcdf4, azure-data-lake-gen2

Trying to read .nc (netCDF4) files in Azure Databricks.

**Never worked with .nc files**

1. All the required .nc files are in Azure Datalake Gen2
2. Mounted above files into Databricks at "`/mnt/eco_dailyRain`"
3. Can list the content of mount using `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/eco_dailyRain")`
   OUTPUT:

   ```
   Out[76]: [FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2000.daily_rain.nc', name='2000.daily_rain.nc', size=429390127),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc', name='2001.daily_rain.nc', size=428217143),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2002.daily_rain.nc', name='2002.daily_rain.nc', size=428218181),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2003.daily_rain.nc', name='2003.daily_rain.nc', size=428217139),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2004.daily_rain.nc', name='2004.daily_rain.nc', size=429390143),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2005.daily_rain.nc', name='2005.daily_rain.nc', size=428217137),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2006.daily_rain.nc', name='2006.daily_rain.nc', size=428217127),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2007.daily_rain.nc', name='2007.daily_rain.nc', size=428217143),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2008.daily_rain.nc', name='2008.daily_rain.nc', size=429390137),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2009.daily_rain.nc', name='2009.daily_rain.nc', size=428217127),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2010.daily_rain.nc', name='2010.daily_rain.nc', size=428217134),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2011.daily_rain.nc', name='2011.daily_rain.nc', size=428218181),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2012.daily_rain.nc', name='2012.daily_rain.nc', size=429390127),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2013.daily_rain.nc', name='2013.daily_rain.nc', size=428217143),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2014.daily_rain.nc', name='2014.daily_rain.nc', size=428218104),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2015.daily_rain.nc', name='2015.daily_rain.nc', size=428217134),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2016.daily_rain.nc', name='2016.daily_rain.nc', size=429390127),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2017.daily_rain.nc', name='2017.daily_rain.nc', size=428217223),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2018.daily_rain.nc', name='2018.daily_rain.nc', size=418143765),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2019.daily_rain.nc', name='2019.daily_rain.nc', size=370034113),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/Consignments.parquet', name='Consignments.parquet', size=237709917),
    FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/test.nc', name='test.nc', size=428217137)]
   ```

Just to test wether can read from mount.

```
spark.read.parquet('dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/Consignments.parquet')
```

confirms can read parquet file.

output

```
Out[83]: DataFrame[CONSIGNMENT_PK: int, CERTIFICATE_NO: string, ACTOR_NAME: string, GENERATOR_FK: int, TRANSPORTER_FK: int, RECEIVER_FK: int, REC_POST_CODE: string, WASTEDESC: string, WASTE_FK: int, GEN_LICNUM: string, VOLUME: int, MEASURE: string, WASTE_TYPE: string, WASTE_ADD: string, CONTAMINENT1_FK: int, CONTAMINENT2_FK: int, CONTAMINENT3_FK: int, CONTAMINENT4_FK: int, TREATMENT_FK: int, ANZSICODE_FK: int, VEH1_REGNO: string, VEH1_LICNO: string, VEH2_REGNO: string, VEH2_LICNO: string, GEN_SIGNEE: string, GEN_DATE: timestamp, TRANS_SIGNEE: string, TRANS_DATE: timestamp, REC_SIGNEE: string, REC_DATE: timestamp, DATECREATED: timestamp, DISCREPANCY: string, APPROVAL_NUMBER: string, TR_TYPE: string, REC_WASTE_FK: int, REC_WASTE_TYPE: string, REC_VOLUME: int, REC_MEASURE: string, DATE_RECEIVED: timestamp, DATE_SCANNED: timestamp, HAS_IMAGE: string, LASTMODIFIED: timestamp]
```

But trying to read `netCDF4` files says `No such file or directory`

Code:

```
import datetime as dt  # Python standard library datetime  module
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset  # http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rootgrp = Dataset("dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc","r", format="NETCDF4")
```

Error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc'
```

Any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API reference of `netCDF4 module` for class [`Dataset`](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Dataset), as the figure below.

[image]

The value of the `path` parameter for `Dataset` should be a path of unix directory format, but the path `dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc` is a format for PySpark as I known, so you got the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc'`.

The solution to fix it is to change the path value `dbfs:/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc` with the equivalence unix path `/dbfs/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc`, the code as below.

```
rootgrp = Dataset("/dbfs/mnt/eco_dailyRain/2001.daily_rain.nc","r", format="NETCDF4")
```

You can check it via the code below to see it.

```
%sh
ls /dbfs/mnt/eco_dailyRain
```

Ofcouse, you also can list your data files of netCDF4 format via `dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/eco_dailyRain')` if you had mount it.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Other thing is instead mounting files to Databricks can i read straight from Azure Data Lake, File path  is "wasbs://ecoscience@desadls.blob.core.windows.net/daily_rain/2001.daily_rain.nc"