# how to open and read .nc files?

Tags: python, scipy

I had a problem of opening `.nc` files and converting them to `.csv` files but still, I can not read them (meaning the first part). I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082101/read-nc-files-from-azure-datalake-gen2-in-azure-databricks) link also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360469/read-nc-netcdf-files-using-python) link  but I could not find out how to open them. I have written a piece of code and I faced an error which I will post below. To elaborate on the error, it is able to find the files but is not able to open them.

```
#from netCDF4 import Dataset  # use scipy instead
from scipy.io import netcdf #### <--- This is the library to import.
import os
# Open file in a netCDF reader
directory = './'
#wrf_file_name = directory+'filename' 
wrf_file_name =  [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.endswith('.nc')]
nc = netcdf.netcdf_file(wrf_file_name,'r')

#Look at the variables available
nc.variables

#Look at the dimensions
nc.dimensions
```

And the error is:

```
Error: LAKE00000002-GloboLakes-L3S-LSWT-v4.0-fv01.0.nc is not a valid NetCDF 3 file
```

Comment: Based on the error you have a data problem. Upload your file here to check https://pumatest.nerc.ac.uk/cgi-bin/cf-checker.pl

Comment: Note that SciPy only handles up to netcdf3.  It does not handle netcdf4 files.